# SVG element bound using knockout not appearing

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js

This is my first project using knockout and i'm running into a problem trying to databind an svg object.  This is being done in a partial view.  I have an svg path defined at the top of the section as so:

```
   <svg class="is-hidden">
    <defs>
        <path id="shape--sort-up" d="M 4 5 L 4 7 L 11 7 L 11 5 L 7.5 1.5 L 4 5 Z" />
    </defs>
   </svg>
```

inside a  im trying to do a conditional visible bind on the svg as so:

```
 <svg data-bind="visible: status == 'yes'" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="icon shape--sort-up">
    <title>status</title>
    <use xlink:href="#shape--sort-up"></use>
 </svg>
```

I have implemented it just using an image instead of a svg and it works fine that way.  When I try to do it with an svg, nothing is shown on the page.  Visual studio is telling me that it doesnt like the xlink attribute being used like this, but it doesn't if the svg is defined outside of a knockout binding.

Comment: Is `status` an observable? If so, you'll need to use `visible: status() == 'yes'`

Comment: no status is not an observable

Comment: I had this working fine with using a .png with <img> data binding instead of the svg.

Comment: Mertis, it's probably something weird with SVG namespaces and dom manipulation. In my experience with Knockout+SVG, it works out to use knockout to bind to attributes, but to stay away from anything else. Did you try putting your visible binding on a container div for the svg? Are you sure knockout is the problem, or could your `<use/>` be failing?

Comment: I had some odd issue with my environment.  I remapped my drive to source control, input the code in my original question, and it worked no problem.